# Evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0} \ln\left(\frac{\cos x}{1+\sin x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, logarithms

How to evaluate this limit?

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \ln\left(\frac{\cos x}{1+\sin x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}$$

I think, somehow it can be transformed to expression, similar to $\frac{\ln (1+x)}{x}$
which limit is equal to $1$, but how?
Can you help?$

Comment: are you allowed to apply _L'Hospital's rule_? If not, make sure you accept some correct one you find useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using L'Hopital's Rule, we have
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}\ln\left(\frac{\cos x}{1+\sin x}\right)^{1/x}&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(\cos x)-\ln(1+\sin x)}{x}\\
&=\lim_{x\to0}\left(-\tan x-\frac{\cos x}{1+\sin x}\right)\\
&=-1
\end{align}

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+x+to+0+ln%28%28cosx%2F%281%2Bsinx%29%29%5E%281%2Fx%29%29) agrees.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Use the fact that $\ln u^v = v \ln u$ and the Taylor expansion for $\cos x$, $\sin x$; then use again the Taylor expansion of $\ln (1+x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

$ L=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln \frac{\cos x}{1+\sin x}}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\frac{\cos x}{1+\sin x}-1}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos x-1-\sin x}{x(1+\sin x)}=\lim_{x \to 0}(-\sin x-\cos x)=-1 $

Comment: $ x\to 1,\ln x=\ln (1+x-1) \to x-1 $

Comment: $ x\to 0,\ln(1+x) \to x,x\to 1,x-1\to 0,\ln (1+x-1) \to x-1 $

Comment: Please give me a reason

Comment: $ x \to 0,\frac{\cos x}{1+\sin x} \to 1 $

Comment: $\frac{\cos x-1-\sin x}{x(1+\sin x}=\frac{\cos x-1}{x(1+\sin x}-\frac{\sin x}{x(1+\sin x)}$. Where the first expresion doesn't have a limit the way you wrote it. I see the first part, but you have to finish it. Your last argument is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

For $1+\sin x\ne0,$ $$\dfrac{\cos x}{1+\sin x}=\dfrac{1-\tan\dfrac x2}{1+\tan\dfrac x2}=1+\dfrac{-2\tan\dfrac x2}{1+\tan\dfrac x2}$$

$$\lim_{x\to0}\left(\dfrac{\cos x}{1+\sin x}\right)^{1/x}$$

$$=\left(\lim_{x\to0}\left(1+\dfrac{-2\tan\dfrac x2}{1+\tan\dfrac x2}\right)^{-\dfrac{1+\tan\dfrac x2}{2\tan\dfrac x2}}\right)^{-\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\tan\dfrac x2}{\dfrac x2\left(1+\tan\dfrac x2\right)}}$$

Set $\dfrac{1+\tan\dfrac x2}{-2\tan\dfrac x2}=y$ to find the inner limit converges to $e$

Now find the limit of exponent

Answer (score 0):

We have
\begin{aligned}
\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\ln\left(\frac{\cos x}{1+\sin x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}&=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\ln(1+(\cos x-1))-\ln(1+\sin x)}{x}\right)\\
&=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\ln(1+(\cos x-1))}{x(\cos x-1)}\cdot\frac{\cos x-1}{x}\cdot x-\frac{\ln(1+\sin x)}{x\sin x}\cdot \sin  x\right)\end{aligned}

Can you continue?